# how to pick an element that is nested to dynamically change it through js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Dear people of Stack overflow; I am having trouble with js in selecting a "div" with js "on-click"
[this are the divs in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzVnu.png)

[image]

```
.mediumSquare {
    height:256px;
    width:50%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #eee;

    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

-this is the css that styles the div general parameters in question

-And here we would have the js that changes the dynamic styles and I would like it to select one of this boxes on click and change their background color...

```
function updateTextInput(val, event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    selector = this;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[type="range"]').each(function() {
        colorPalettes(this.id);
    });

    $('.mediumSquare > div').on('click', function(event) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
    });
});
```

And this is the relevant Html

```
<div class='colorScope'>
    <div class='mediumSquare'><div id="colorBackgroundDark<%=project.id%>"></div>
        <div id="Dark1<%=project.id%>">
        </div>
        <div id="Dark2<%=project.id%>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='mediumSquare'><div id="colorBackgroundLight<%=project.id%>"></div>
        <div id="Light1<%=project.id%>">
        </div>
        <div id="Light2<%=project.id%>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is my current approach

this is the ranger

```
<input type="range" class="slider" id="<%=project.id%>" min="0" max="16777215" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value,this.id);">
```

Another problem I am having is when I focus on the ranger it becomes current target so I cannot pick a color to change it with the ranger with js styling.

Comment: What is the result of the click? nothing at all? any errors in the console?

Comment: the thing is it is not currently picking or changing the colors with shoulc be doing with my slider

Comment: I didn't see any code to change background color ,and where's the div that with attr 'type' and value 'range', what would the function 'colorPalettes'  do ? maybe you need to explain your problem more clearly~

Comment: I added the ranger aswell...